# Sending two post request with html form and AJAX at once

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post

I´m trying to make two POST requests to different sites:

One from the action attribute form tag , and the otherone using AJAX (specifically XMLHttpRequest) on the onsubmit event.

Here is a snippet I made that **IS WORKING on chrome browser** (it sends first the ajax POST and then the form post) , but **IT DOESN´T work in firefox** (it only sends the POST action form).

**Form action POST request**

```bash
<form name="form_log" method="POST" action="Site1.php" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

**AJAX POST request**

```bash
function validate(){
    if(document.form_log.username.value == ""){
        alert('User name is empty');
        return false;
    }

    if(document.form_log.password.value == ""){
        alert('Password is empty');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        var user=document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value;
        var pass=document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;
        var parameters=`username=${user}&password=${pass}&Submit=Enter`;
        var url = "http://Site2.php";
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open('POST',url,true);

        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
            if(xhttp.DONE && xhttp.status == 200){
                console.log("SENT!");
            }
        }
        xhttp.send(parameters);
    }   
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, and this behaviour is due to a Firefox restriction?

Thanks in advance !!

I tried this snippet on chrome and works OK! , but I can´t make to send both POST request on Firefox (it only sends the POST action request).

Comment: Possibly a CORS issue?

Comment: I don´t think so, because in chrome it works. 
Also  "site2.php" has cors permission for any origin:
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");